# amqp:outbound-gateway throwing ReplyRequiredException

Tags: spring-integration

- I am using int-amqp:outbound-gateway to create a message in Rabbit. The message is published but my flow stops with ReplyRequiredException 
  setPublisherReturns and setPublisherConfirms are set on the CachingConnectionFactory
- when I set requires-reply to 'false' the thread is frozen and doesn't continue

Code:

```
<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplateCore"  connection-factory="connectionFactoryCore"  />
<bean id="connectionFactoryCore" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject"><ref bean="rabbitConfiguration" /></property>
        <property name="targetMethod"><value>connectionFactory</value></property>
    </bean>

<int-amqp:outbound-gateway
        request-channel="requestIn"
        reply-channel="requestOut"
        amqp-template="amqpTemplateCore" 
        exchange-name="CDS"
        routing-key="keyA">
</int-amqp:outbound-gateway>

bean:
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory(host);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(virtualhost);
        connectionFactory.setPort(port);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(username);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
        connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
        return (ConnectionFactory)connectionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `outbound-gateway` is for `request/reply` scenario. When you send something to an external system and wait for reply from there.

If your logic is one-way, just to send and forget, consider to use `<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

Comment: I can't use <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter> because my requirement is to make sure that the message has been sent before invoking the next step

Comment: so why I am not getting a reply from amqp:outbound-gateway?

Comment: ??? The other side, listener must send you reply back. In case of `sendAndReceive` there is `ReplyTo` header in the request message. And sender has started to be listener for that reply queue. That's how it waits for reply. But if your logic isn't send reply back, but just place it into queue on Broker, you don't have choice unless use `outbound-channel-adapter`. Right, you can configure there `confirm-ack-channel` to be sure that the message is placed to the queue correctly and go ahead with good result.